# AWS metadata: Check if EC2 instance is spot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

There's a [AWS metadata](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html) service which provides some information about the EC2 instance that issues a request to `http://169.254.169.254/`. I'm wondering if there's a way to know from that metadata if the instance is "Spot" or "On Demand"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The information is not available inside the metadata.

However, you can get the instance ID from the metadata, then call ec2-describe-instances to get instance information about your instance.  Inside that instance description is the spot instance request ID.  If blank, then it's not a spot instance, otherwise, it's a spot instance.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I've been looking for this for a while and must have overlooked it when looking at the instance data.

Comment: I see no key called 'spot instance request ID' in the json printed. I did: `aws ec2 describe-instances` and I am using AWS CLI 2.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe they have this information in the metadata.

You could assign a different profile for instances you launch as spot instances and use the profile name to determine what type of instance it is. If that doesn't seem like a clean or viable solution you can always grab the instance-id from the meta data then run the command `ec2-describe-spot-instance-requests --filter instance-id=<instanceid>` if the command returns empty than the instance is not a spot instance, if the command returns with data then it's a spot instance.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is super old but if anyone wants a one liner:

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-instance-requests \
  --filters Name=instance-id,Values="$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)" \
  --region us-east-1 | \
  jq -r '.SpotInstanceRequests | if length > 0 then "spot" else "normal" end'
```

Adjust `--region` accordingly

https://gist.github.com/urjitbhatia/c5af8a3d53661cb3d4e896feae23fc1d

Answer (score 3):

A little improved version of that of @urjit:

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-instance-requests \
  --filters Name=instance-id,Values="$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)" \
  --region "$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/.$//')" | \
  jq -r '.SpotInstanceRequests | if length > 0 then "Ec2Spot" else "OnDemand" end'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like things changed with the years, so now it works

```bash
# a spot instance
$ curl -s --fail http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-life-cycle
spot
# a normal instance
$ curl -s --fail http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-life-cycle
on-demand
```